# How to share args in two sub commands for argparser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

For example, there're two sub_commands `run` and `batch-run`, the `run` parser looks like this:

```
parser_run = sub_parsers.add_parser("run")
parser_run.add_argument("-c", "--config", dest="config", required=True,
    help="specify the config file to use", )

parser_run.add_argument("--from", dest="start_step", default=0, type=int,
    help="Only step after this number will be processed")
parser_run.add_argument("--to", dest="end_step", default=100, type=int,
    help="Only step before this number will be processed ")
parser_run.add_argument("--skip", dest="skip_step", default="",
    help="Steps to skip, use comma as seperator")

parser_run.add_argument("-v", "--verbose-level", dest="verbose_level", type=int, default=2)
parser_run.add_argument("--dry-run", dest="dry_run", action="store_true", default=False)
parser_run.add_argument("--allow-dangling", dest="allow_dangling", action="store_true", default=False)
parser_run.add_argument("--resume", dest="resume", action="store_true", default=False)
parser_run.add_argument("--remove", dest="clean", action="store_true", default=False)
```

Now I need to write the `batch` parser, which has all the arguments of `run` but the `-c` (it uses `-b` instead to specified the batch-config file). I was just wondering whether I need to copy and paste all the codes of `add_argument` to the `batch`parser. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parser_run` object is just that, an object, so you can assign it to another variable, use a loop, etc:

```
parser_run = sub_parsers.add_parser("run")
parser_run.add_argument("-c", "--config", dest="config", required=True,
    help="specify the config file to use", )

parser_batch = sub_parsers.add_parser("batch")
parser_batch.add_argument("-b", "--batch-config", dest="config", required=True,
    help="specify the batch config file to use", )

for sub_parser in (parser_run, parser_batch):
    sub_parser.add_argument("--from", dest="start_step", default=0, type=int,
        help="Only step after this number will be processed")
    sub_parser.add_argument("--to", dest="end_step", default=100, type=int,
        help="Only step before this number will be processed ")
    sub_parser.add_argument("--skip", dest="skip_step", default="",
        help="Steps to skip, use comma as seperator")

    sub_parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose-level", dest="verbose_level", type=int, default=2)
    sub_parser.add_argument("--dry-run", dest="dry_run", action="store_true", default=False)
    sub_parser.add_argument("--allow-dangling", dest="allow_dangling", action="store_true", default=False)
    sub_parser.add_argument("--resume", dest="resume", action="store_true", default=False)
    sub_parser.add_argument("--remove", dest="clean", action="store_true", default=False)
```

Now both sub parsers have the same arguments added.